# Facebook: List of subscribers

Tags: facebook

I want to get a list of people who has subscribed to my updates. How can I get that in new *Facebook Timeline*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct link that will work for anyone is this http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?sk=subscribers

---

**Original answer:**

There are 2 options, if you have claimed & know your unique username (not your email used to login), just enter this address: `http://facebook.com/USERNAME/subscribers` (replacing `USERNAME` with your own).

If you don't know it, go to your profile, click on the arrow with a number in the row of tiles where your friends & photos are and you'll see the link to subscribers.