# How can I view my followers on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Facebook must have changed something again because I cannot find out how to view the list of subscribers.  In Googling for this, I came upon this question:

[Facebook: List of subscribers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22581/facebook-list-of-subscribers)

However, it doesn't take me to my list os subscribers.  Where do I view this list now?

*Please include a screenshot and highlight the link I need to click on*.  This way, when Facebook changes their layout again, your screenshot will at least clue future inquirers in on this fact so they know they're not going crazy.

**Edit**

Here's what I see when I log into Facebook:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to get the list of people who are following you.

- In your profile page, a link from the about section

[image]

- In your 'Friends' section, click on the Followers tab

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screens, but I just don't see that link.  The last time I checked which was recently, all my friends were followers.  Also, FWIW, I have followers turned on.

Comment: That's strange now. I had turned on new Graph search sometime ago. I am also able to see my followers by going to http://www.facebook.com/<profilename>/followers. Can you just make sure that 'Followers' settings is still on by using this URL: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=followers

Comment: Yep, followers is on.  Going to that /followers link just takes me to my profile with my Friends tab selected.  I also posted screens in my question of what I see.  I really hate FB sometimes.

Comment: Well, I must say I do not have an answer then. Let's wait for someone else to respond. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason why you are not seeing any follower list is because you have no followers.

Try going to the "View As" link

[image: View As]

and you should be seeing something similar to

[image: Followed by]

As long as you see the "Followed by" section in about, you should have followers.

Also a next way to confirm this is by a Graph API request

`HTTP GET https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_USER_ID/subscribers?access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: I do not see this, so either 1) FB dropped all my followers or 2) all my friends stopped following me within the span of a month.  Prior to this, all my friends were listed as followers.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin this was an old way of the subscription model. Previously your subscribers were your friends and non-friends who subscribed. Now your friend subscriptions have turned into "show on news feed". Your real subscriptions are only made up of non-friends who follow you.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Facebook didn't drop your followers, because all your previous "followers" were just friends. Your friends didn't stop following you, their "following" activity has been converted in the form of "show on news feed"

Comment: What I should have said is that FB removed all followers that explicitly didn't follow me (as opposed to showing all friends as followers unless they explicitly unfollow me).  But I think you're right and will probably mark yours as answer soon.